# Large Images animation

Tags: qt, qml

I have a problem with large images animation in Qt/QML. I got a sequence of images (the animation is too complex for me to do that in other way) each image is in fullHD resolution. By using Timer, I'm trying to set "source" attribute of Image component in this way:

```
Image {
  source: "0.png"
  Timer {
    running: true
    interval: parseInt(1000 / 30) //30 - fps
    repeat: true

    property int currentImage: 0
    onTriggered: {
      parent.source = (++currentImage) + ".png"
    }
  }
}
```

It's only an example so it doesn't matter it never ends. The problem is that the animation isn't smooth even on stronger PC.

Sprites are not an option because used images are to big to create a sprite. With lower images resolution - everything plays quite nice but the quality in this case isn't enough for me.

Its to late to use any game engine for me so I would like to ask you about any other options to solve my problem

Comment: This seems like something that would be better off as a video so that you get whatever hardware acceleration already exists for that? If you have to do it this way, you could load all of the images on startup (rather than as you need them) so that they're cached (the cache property is true by default). That might improve the performance.

Comment: All images have alpha channel so I don't know if video is a good idea here. Maybe I'm wrong but imho its not possible to keep that with video.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested with loading them all at startup? Does it improve the smoothness at all? How many images are there?

Comment: Loading them at startup helps, but one animation takes around 500MB of RAM (50 images, 100/200KB each) its strange that it takes so much.